# TIMEDIFF in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, html, perl, datetime, interchange

TIMEDIFF in MYSQL
I am using Interchange IC (http://interchange.rtfm.info/icdocs/index.html)

```
[query list=1 sql="SELECT TIMEDIFF(NOW(),'[sql-param time]') as diff"]
my $vardifftime = [sql-param diff];
```

`$vardifftime` It is giving output blank.
I want no of hours between current time and datetime type column in mysql database. 
[sql-param time] stores datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ROUND((UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-UNIX_TIMESTAMP('[sql-param time]'))/3600);
```

Comment: Thanks but I am working on windows I don know why you have used UNIX_TIMESTAMP

Comment: Sry. I wasnt aware of this functionality its working fine on mysql but on html page its not

Answer (score 1):

Is `[sql-param time]` is of `datetime` cause `timediff` expects both expression to be of same type. If [sql-param time] is time only then probably you can do like

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(TIME(NOW()),'[sql-param time]') as diff
```

Comment: Thanks but I am still getting null output on my html page its working fine on mysql